# How to create multiple beans of PubSubTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to create two beans of `PubSubTemplate` class to set different message converter.
I am having two subscriber among them one is receiving `Json` response and another one is receiving `String` response. To handle these two scenario I am creating two `PubSubTemplate` bean.
Below is my `PubSubTemplateConfig.java` :

```
@Configuration
public class PubSubTemplateConfig {

    @Bean
    public PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplateForUserCreation(PubSubPublisherTemplate pubSubPublisherTemplate,
              PubSubSubscriberTemplate pubSubSubscriberTemplate) {
        PubSubTemplate template = new PubSubTemplate(pubSubPublisherTemplate, pubSubSubscriberTemplate);
        template.setMessageConverter(new JacksonPubSubMessageConverter(getObjectMapper()));
        return template;
    }
    
    private ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        return objectMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplateForAuditTracker(PubSubPublisherTemplate pubSubPublisherTemplate,
              PubSubSubscriberTemplate pubSubSubscriberTemplate) {
        PubSubTemplate template = new PubSubTemplate(pubSubPublisherTemplate, pubSubSubscriberTemplate);
        template.setMessageConverter(new SimplePubSubMessageConverter());
        return template;
    }
    
}
```

Below two are the subscriber configuration :
`AuditsubscriptioncriptionConfiguration.java`

```
@Configuration
public class AuditsubscriptioncriptionConfiguration {
    
    @Value("${subscriptioncription.auditsubscriptioncription}")
    private String subscription;
    
    @Bean("pubsubAuditInputChannel")
    public MessageChannel pubsubAuditInputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PubSubInboundChannelAdapter auditMessageChannelAdapter(@Qualifier("pubsubAuditInputChannel") MessageChannel pubsubAuditInputChannel,
            @Qualifier("pubSubTemplateForAuditTracker") PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplateForAuditTracker) {
     
        PubSubInboundChannelAdapter adapter = new PubSubInboundChannelAdapter(pubSubTemplateForAuditTracker, subscription);
        adapter.setOutputChannel(pubsubAuditInputChannel);
        adapter.setPayloadType(String.class); //need changes
        adapter.setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL);
        return adapter;
    }    

}
```

And `UserSubscriptionConfiguration.java`

```
@Configuration
public class UserSubscriptionConfiguration {
    
    @Value("${subscription.userSubscriber}")
    private String subscriber;
    
    @Bean("pubsubInputChannel")
    public MessageChannel pubsubInputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
     
    @Bean
    public PubSubInboundChannelAdapter userMessageChannelAdapter(@Qualifier("pubsubInputChannel") MessageChannel pubsubInputChannel,
            @Qualifier("pubSubTemplateForUserCreation") PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplateForUserCreation) {
     
        PubSubInboundChannelAdapter adapter = new PubSubInboundChannelAdapter(pubSubTemplateForUserCreation, subscriber);
        adapter.setOutputChannel(pubsubInputChannel);
        adapter.setPayloadType(UserChangeEvent.class);
        adapter.setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL);
        return adapter;
    }
}
```

Steps I observed during container start up :

Step 1. First `pubSubTemplateForAuditTracker` bean is getting created with `SimplePubSubMessageConverter` and then `AuditMessageChannelAdapter` bean is getting configured

Step 2. `pubSubTemplateForUserCreation` bean is getting created with `JacksonPubSubMessageConverter` and `userMessageChannelAdapter` is getting configured

Here, I should have two beans with two different message converter but while debugging I found that only one instance of `PubSubTemplate` is present and the attached message converter is `JacksonPubSubMessageConverter`. `pubSubTemplateForAuditTracker` bean is getting overridden with `pubSubTemplateForUserCreation` bean though I had defined them twice with `@Bean` annotation. This behavior is leading to an Error when `auditMessageChannelAdapter` is receiving a `String` message
My expectation is I want to have two separate `PubSubTemplate` bean with two different Message Converter.
Basically I want to create two beans of type `PubSubTemplate` with different behaviour.
Can someone please help me here.
I am exploring GCP pub/sub for the first time. Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to connect to two different subs? Do you want to stick with PubSubTemplate or are you open for different approaches?

Comment: @AlexTbk Yes I am connecting to two different subs. I can try different approach. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You can manually create multiple subscriptions like this

```
@PostConstruct
private void subscribeWithConcurrencyControl() {
    // create subscription
    TopicName topic = TopicName.ofProjectTopicName(projectId, this.eventTopic);

    Subscription subscription = Subscription.newBuilder()
            .setName("projects/XYZ/subscriptions/" + eventSubscription)
            .setTopic(topic.toString())
            .setPushConfig(PushConfig.getDefaultInstance())
            .setAckDeadlineSeconds(100)
            .build();

    Subscription subscription2 = Subscription.newBuilder()
            .setName("projects/XYZ/subscriptions/" + eventSubscription2)
            .setTopic(topic.toString())
            .setPushConfig(PushConfig.getDefaultInstance())
            .setAckDeadlineSeconds(100)
            .build();

    try {
        client.createSubscription(subscription);
    } catch (AlreadyExistsException e) {
        // nothing to do
    }

    try {
        client.createSubscription(subscription2);
    } catch (AlreadyExistsException e) {
        // nothing to do
    }

    ProjectSubscriptionName subscriptionName1 = ProjectSubscriptionName.of(projectId, eventSubscription);
    ProjectSubscriptionName subscriptionName2 = ProjectSubscriptionName.of(projectId, eventSubscription2);

    // Instantiate an asynchronous message receiver.
    MessageReceiver receiver = (PubsubMessage message, AckReplyConsumer consumer) -> {
        // Handle incoming message, then ack the received message.
        try {
            process(message);
            consumer.ack();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Failed to process message", e);
            consumer.nack();
        }
    };

    // Provides an executor service for processing messages. The default `executorProvider` used
    // by the subscriber has a default thread count of 5.
    ExecutorProvider executorProvider =
            InstantiatingExecutorProvider.newBuilder().setExecutorThreadCount(2).build();

    FlowControlSettings flowControlSettings =
            FlowControlSettings.newBuilder()
                    .setMaxOutstandingElementCount(100L)
                    .build();

    // `setParallelPullCount` determines how many StreamingPull streams the subscriber will open
    // to receive message. It defaults to 1. `setExecutorProvider` configures an executor for the
    // subscriber to process messages. Here, the subscriber is configured to open 2 streams for
    // receiving messages, each stream creates a new executor with 4 threads to help process the
    // message callbacks. In total 2x4=8 threads are used for message processing.
    subscriber1 = Subscriber.newBuilder(subscriptionName1, receiver)
            .setParallelPullCount(20)
            .setExecutorProvider(executorProvider)
            .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .setFlowControlSettings(flowControlSettings)
            .build();

    subscriber2 = Subscriber.newBuilder(subscriptionName2, receiver)
            .setParallelPullCount(20)
            .setExecutorProvider(executorProvider)
            .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .setFlowControlSettings(flowControlSettings)
            .build();

    // Start the subscriber.
    subscriber1.startAsync().awaitRunning();
    subscriber2.startAsync().awaitRunning();
}
```

In the process() method you can use the usual objectmapper and/or instanceof commands to determine the type of the message (or have different receivers for different subscriptions, or even transport the type of the message in the pubsub headers)

```
    private void process(PubsubMessage message) {
    try {
        ModificationEvent modificationEvent = objectMapper.readValue(message.getData().toStringUtf8(), ModificationEvent.class);
    } catch(...)
```

Comment: In my scenario, two subscriptions are already created in a different GCP project and I am trying to create ```PubSubInboundChannelAdapter``` to receive those responses from respective subscription.

Comment: I dont understand why I am not getting two beans of ```PubSubTemplate```, could you explain me the reason here? Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: If the subs already exist you can omit the client.createSubscription(subscription2); in the code.

Comment: This does not help. Can anyone suggest how to have two beans instantiated of ```PubSubTemplate``` one bean with ```JacksonPubSubMessageConverter``` and another bean with ```SimplePubSubMessageConverter``` ? The way I did, it's not working

Comment: Why doesnt this help? My example is a production code that we use...

Comment: I dont see any InboundChannelAdapter or any MessageChannel, how subscriber will decide where to go. Anyway what are those ```subscriber1 ``` and ```subscriber2``` in your code?

Comment: Subscriber1 gets all mesages from first sub, subscriber2 from the second one